# Read application parameter from web.xml in jspInit()

Tags: jsp

I want to get some init parameters out of web.xml when the web application is initially deployed (or requested for the first time). However, the application implicit object is obviously not available in jspInit(). What other way would there be to read the parameters from web.xml, short of actually manually loading and parsing the xml file?

Comment: try this http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JSP/JSPInitialization.htm

Comment: Isn't that value specific to a certain servlet? I want to read a parameter that's valid for the entire application (i.e. what I would normally read via application.getInitParameter()). Also here the parameter is read from web.xml every time the jsp site is requested. I want to do it specifically in jspInit().

Comment: you can call getServletConfig().getInitParameter in jspInit method